# Present Continuous Passive Voice & Modal Verb

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice

I'd like to explain the following:

> (1) Only one simulation can be published at the same time.

emphasizing the continuous aspect of publishing, like::

> (2) Only one simulation can be **being** published at the same time.

so it won't sound like we can have only one simulation published, while we can have multiple ones, but only one can be in a process of publishing.

*Since the (2) doesn't sound right, I wonder whether it's correct? And how to explain it properly, if it isn't?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be idiomatic to use **get** or **getting** instead of **being** if you  wanted to make really clear that the past participle is to be understood as a process that is underway:

> Only one simulation can be published at the same time.
>
> Only one simulation **can be getting published** at the same time. <sup>clearest</sup>
>
> Only one simulation **can get published** at the same time.
>
> In this double-length bay, two cars **can be getting their oil changed** simultaneously. <sup>clearest</sup>
>
> In this double-length bay, two cars **can get their oil changed** simultaneously.
>
> The oil **can be getting changed** on two cars simultaneously in this double-length bay. <sup>clearest</sup>
>
> The oil **can get changed** on two cars simultaneously in this double-length bay.
>
> The oil can be changed on two cars in this double-length bay.

Answer (score 1):

**(2)** is entirely ungrammatical and should never be used in any circumstances.

There are a few ways to correct the sentence:

> There are multiple simulations, but only one can be in the process of being published.

This isn't as short as the original sentence, but it's succinct and explicit enough to ensure no readers are left confused.

Another would be:

> Out of multiple different simulations, only one can be in the process of being published.

A viable choice that's a bit less clunky than my previous example, while still retaining its clear meaning.

Comment: **In the process of publishing** is not quite idiomatic. **in the process of being published** would be better.

Comment: Point taken. Will be edited in a jiffy. Thanks @Tᴚoɯɐuo